# Intent extras in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Andoird application, i pass extras to other intent by below code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetail.class);
i.putExtra("note_id", note_id);
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

in noteDetail, get extras by this code :

```
if (i.hasExtra(Key_NOTE_ID)) {

    // Must Update the note
    KEY_HAS_NOTE_ID = true;
    noteId = i.getStringExtra(Key_NOTE_ID);
    Log.i("Note Id is >>", noteId.toString());

    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(
            getApplicationContext());
    if (cd.isConnectedToInternet()) {

        new GetNoteDetail().execute();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(NoteDetail.this,
                R.string.not_connected_to_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Application work correctly and extras pass and receive correctly until press back button on mobile phone and back to previous activity. again when i press the noteDetail button and go to noteDetail activity the previous note_id has remained and not clear.
i want to clear extras when user press back button on mobile phone.

Comment: I have a list. list fill by internet. if list don't have any item go to noteDetail activity without note_id extra to save new note. and if click on items list go to noteDetail activity with note_id to update the note.

Comment: The intent extras are not being persisted from one instance to another.  Your problem is more likely in the code that sets the value of `note_id`.  Can you post this section?

Comment: Define note_id : `String noteId;`. then in onCreate code, use `if (i.hasExtra(Key_NOTE_ID)) {....`

Comment: Not in that Activity, in the original one.  The field named `note_id`

Comment: If list don't have item i use : `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
       NoteDetail.class);
     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(i);` and onItemClick i use : `String note_id = ((TextView) view
      .findViewById(R.id.list_lbl_id)).getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetail.class);
    i.putExtra("note_id", note_id);
    startActivityForResult(i, 100);`

Comment: Looks to me like your obtaining of the `note_id` is always getting its value from the same `TextView` and is not based on the selected list item's position.  Are you absolutely sure that each time you make a selection, the value of `note_id` passed in the extra changes?  Because the code seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Yes. `note_id` changed correct when click on list.

Answer (score 2):

In `onPause()` use:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(Key_NOTE_ID)) getIntent().removeExtra(Key_NOTE_ID);
```

Comment: You still have the value or you get exception?

Comment: Yes. Ihave value and not exeption in Locat

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520961/removing-extras-from-passed-in-intent) as I think your problem is that you are checking a value of the old getExtra, i.e. you do not run getExtra again after resume