# Android starting activity using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

In my app I am using `Notification`. When user clicks on this Notification than starts my application(if it not running) or dialog is showing.
In the activity I do checking

```
    intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        mPrice = getIntent().getExtras().getString("price");
        showDialog(mPrice);
    }
```

Everything work good, except when my activity started via Notification, every time when I exit from app using back button and start app again it shows me dialog. I have tried remove this Extras using `getIntent().getExtras().remove("price")` but it doesn't work. How to fix this, that dialog shows only one time if clicked on the Notification?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing extras from passed-in Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520961/removing-extras-from-passed-in-intent)

Answer (score 1):

getExtras creates a copy of the extras.

You need to use

```
getIntent().removeExtra("price");
```

Comment: It does not help. Dialog appears again.

Answer (score -1):

Check that the `getString` actually has returned a value, like this:

```
intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    mPrice = getIntent().getExtras().getString("price");
    if (mPrice != null) showDialog(mPrice);
}
```