# Permanently modify Intent that started an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like send an Intent to start an Activity. I would like to be able to modify that Intent. Then, when the activity is destroyed and recreated, I would like those modifications to still be present when I call `getIntent()`.

Currently, modifying the intent works fine as long as the Activity has not been destroyed. If it has, then when the activity is recreated, it will get the original Intent that started it, and not the copy it received when it was launched the first time that may have modified.

Comment: What for ? Is it only for storing values of extras of the Intent ? Or is there anything else ?

Comment: I am not aware that this is possible, sorry. If you could explain your overall objective, perhaps we can suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's a bit complicated. I'm writing third party code for push intents. The host app launches an intent when the user taps a notification. This Intent launches the main activity for instance. The main activity checks to see if a specific extra data is present, and if so, passes it to my SDK code. I display a UI in that case. The problem is that once my UI closes, I have no easy way of determining if that was the first time I saw the Intent, or the 50th.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Modifying the Intent to remove my extra data works fine as long as the main Activity is still around, but if it's destroyed/recreated, the extra data is back.

That's because you are modifying your local copy of the `Intent`, not the master copy maintained in an OS process, where the task lists are kept.

If this data is truly instance state of the activity, it should be saved as such, via `onSaveInstanceState()`, and you'd get that back via `onRestoreInstanceState()`. The user of your library would need to forward these events on to you.

If you do not wish to consider this to be instance state, but rather process state, store the data in a singleton.

If the data should live beyond the lifetime of a process, write it to disk somewhere.

> I could save the data in the host app's broadcast receiver, and then use and delete it in my code

If by "save the data in the host app's broadcast receiver", that is pointless. A manifest-registered receiver lives for a single broadcast, and then is done.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer. I should have said "save the data from" not "save the data in". I would be saving it to SharedPreferences most likely.

Comment: Furthermore, I consider this to be a design flaw in Android that an Intent can even be modified in such a manner, since most developers have a shaky understanding of the Activity lifecycle to begin with.

Comment: @SkyKelsey: Making `Intent` immutable would be a serious pain in various body parts. :-)

Comment: I guess so, although I don't know of the use cases. But providing an API to get a COPY of the Intent instead of the actual Intent would be better. Or at least documentation letting us know that the Intent dies with the Activity, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right thing to do it. What you want to do is save data right ? In such a case you don't have to mess with intents, just change the values and then save them, the next time the app runs it will load the values from last time, here is some code:

How to save values:

```
//Create sharedPref (It's android's way of saving values)
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

//Save Values here
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);

//Commit changes
editor.commit();
```

How to load values:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
```

More info here: [developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right that I will have to do this. Since I am writing SDK code, I would rather have my code handle all this instead of having the host app have to do it for me. I could save the data in the host app's broadcast receiver, and then use and delete it in my code.

Comment: what do you mean? the way I described saves the values inside the device that the app is installed, and is private from other apps (meaning that only your app can access it)

Comment: Yes, I've very familiar with SharedPreferences. I'm just constrained by the fact that I don't want to add additional lines of code for the developer integrating my SDK into their app if I can avoid it.

Comment: aaah I think I get it now, unfortunately I don't think there is another way, but it's really not that bad way of doing it

Comment: I ended up doing this. I marked the other reply as the answer, as it resolves the question posed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
activity.setIntent(activity.getIntent());
```

Works for me

Comment: that should not work. activity.getIntent() just gives you the reference to the intent inside Activity object. Then you modify the object that this reference points to and set the original reference point to the same object which does not make any scene.